# Those who do certain things will undergo the same

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, identification-request

In Mahabharata, Krishna told a sentence with similar meaning

> Those who do the things in a particular context will have to face the  same
>   things on the same circumstances

These lines may be the lines Krishna told Draupadi or to some other regarding Kauravas. Where can I find the exact lines told by Krishna?

Comment: I think Bhishma said this to Yudhishtira in Shanthi Parva - think it starts with 'yad-yad.. tad-tad'

Comment: @ram Yes this question is a duplicate. I read about yad yad tad tad on a question a couple of weeks ago but I am unable to find it.

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria but I asked about Krishna's words explicitly

Comment: But at that time I thought that Krishna talked this regarding Kauravas, but recently found that it was about Jarasandha...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement asked in the question was told by Krishna to Jarasandha in the following [excerpt](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02022.htm) of [Sabha Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/index.htm) of Mahabaratha

> "Krishna said,--'O thou of mighty arms, there is a certain person of
>   the head of a (royal) line who upholdeth the dignity of his race At
>   his command have we come against thee. Thou hast brought, O king, many
>   of the Kshatriyas of the world as captives (to thy city.) Having
>   perpetrated that wicked wrong how dost thou regard thyself as
>   innocent? O best of monarchs, how can a king act wrongfully towards
>   other virtuous kings? But thou, O king, treating other kings with
>   cruelty, seekest to offer them as sacrifice unto the god Rudra! O son
>   of Vrihadratha, this sin committed by thee may touch even us, for as
>   we are virtuous in our practices, we are capable of protecting virtue.
>   The slaughter of human being as sacrifice unto the gods is never seen.
>   Why dost thou, therefore, seek to perform a sacrifice unto god Sankara
>   by slaughtering human beings? Thou art addressing persons belonging to
>   thy own order as animals (fit for sacrifice)! Fool as thou art, who
>   else, O Jarasandha, is capable of behaving in this way? **One always
>   obtaineth the fruits of whatever acts one performeth under whatever
>   circumstances.** Therefore, desirous as we are of helping all distressed
>   people, we have, for the prosperity of our race, come hither to slay
>   thee, the slaughterer of our relatives. Thou thinkest that there is no
>   man among the Kshatriyas (equal to thee). This, O king, is a great
>   error of judgment on thy part. What Kshatriya is there, O king, who
>   endued with greatness of soul and recollecting the dignity of his own
>   parentage, would not ascend to eternal heaven that hath not its like
>   anywhere, falling in open fight? Know O bull among men, that
>   Kshatriyas engage themselves in battle, as persons installed in
>   sacrifices, with heaven in view, and vanquish the whole world! Study
>   of the Vedas, great fame, ascetic penances, and death in battle, are
>   all acts that lead to heaven. The attainment of heaven by the three
>   other acts may be uncertain, but death in battle hath that for its
>   certain consequence. Death in battle is the sure cause of triumph like
>   Indra's. It is graced by numerous merits. It is for this reason that
>   he of a hundred sacrifices (Indra) hath become what he is, and by
>   vanquishing the Asuras he ruleth the universe. Hostility with whom
>   else than thee is so sure of leading to heaven, proud as thou art of
>   the excessive strength of thy vast Magadha host? Don't disregard
>   others, O king. Valour dwelleth in every man. O king of men, there are
>   many men whose valour may be equal or superior to thine. As long as
>   these are not known, so long only art thou noted for thy valour. Thy
>   prowess, O king, can be borne by us. It is, therefore, that I say so.
>   O king of Magadha, cast off thy superiority and pride in the presence
>   of those that are thy equals. Go not, O king, with thy children and
>   ministers and army, into the regions of Yama. Damvodhava, Kartavirya,
>   Uttara, and Vrihadratha, were kings that met with destruction, along
>   with all their forces, for having disregarded their superiors.
>   Desirous of liberating the captive monarchs from thee, know that we
>   are certainly not Brahmanas. I am Hrishesha otherwise called Sauri,
>   and these two heroes among men are the sons of Pandu. O king of
>   Magadha, we challenge thee. Fight standing before us. Either set free
>   all the monarchs, or go thou to the abode of Yama.